# Team Build to build solution in different TFS Projects

Tags: tfs, build-process, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

We are using TFS2008 and TeamBuid to build our product.  I have SolutionAA in TeamProjectAA that uses a file reference to a compiled library (SolutionBB) that is checked in to TeamProjectAA.  Now this works fine.  Now the source code to the library is checked in TeamProjectBB.  The problem arises when I need to due a full build using TeamBuild.  I have a build project for SolutionAA but I need to compile SolutionBB and version is correctly so it can be distributed with our install.

Is there a way to chain two TeamBuilds together?  Or can I build a solution from another TFS project from another TFS project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post (http://bit.ly/tfschaining) which contains an example Custom Task which can queue a build.

Your full build can start by running build AA and then queue build BB.

I would suggest, though, that you get a better versioning scheme for your dependencies.  You are running AA as if it is an independent project and should treat it's output as such in BB.  Consider pulling manually from AA as you it suites your status on BB.  That way BB can have intermediate builds and BB can only pull when its ready to take on the changes in AA.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking in the compiled library as part of the TFS Build for SolutionBB. Then, include the location of that compiled library in your workspace mapping for the TFS Build of SolutionAA and configure it with a continuous integration trigger. The build of SolutionAA will get triggered whenever the compiled library for SolutionBB is modified in version control.